# What physical phenomena underly the shape of this graph of diurnal UV index?

Tags: visible-light, diffraction, atmospheric-science

When I [dig up a graphs of UV index versus time-of-day](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=diurnal+uv+index), most graphs are characteristically shaped like one of the plots shown here:

[image]

That graph is from [this site](http://weather.vouhead.gr/wxuv-1.php?lang=en).

1. What physical phenomena underly that characteristic shape?
2. Is there a (perhaps simplified and approximate) function for UV index versus latitude and time of day if we assume constant atmospheric conditions and altitude?

Answer (score 4):

This is a part answer to your questions, specifically the first one (as I have worked and published in this field):

According to the National Weather Service, Climate Prediction Centre page [UV Index: Information](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_diurnal.shtml), the characteristic overall shape that you see in the image you have included is due to

> UV radiation is much more attenuated than the global at high solar zenith angles in the early morning and late afternoon. This is because the two components which make up UV and all other forms of radiation; the direct and the diffuse, are both greatly affected at these low sun angles.

Specifically, during the late afternoon or early morning, the UV radiation has to 'travel' a greater distance through the atmosphere due to a greater angle the sun is from zenith (in other words, has a greater relative [air mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_mass_%28solar_energy%29))  (Illustrated below).

[image]

[Image source](http://www.instesre.org/Activities/RelativeAirMass.htm)

From the NWS web page:

> Direct UV radiation is greatly reduced by the increased absorption by stratospheric ozone during its increased path length through the atmosphere (about 6 times more than when the sun is directly overhead).

So, greater amount of time away from local noon = greater sun zenith angle = greater relative air mass for the UV radiation to travel through = greater UV attenuation = lower UVI

In regards to your second question, some measurements have been made by the World Health Organisation's [InterSun program](http://www.who.int/uv/intersunprogramme/activities/uv_index/en/index3.html), where realistically, there are too many factors that affect the UV Index to form a pattern according to latitude alone, specifically according to [Know Your UV Index](http://dermatology.about.com/od/skincancers/a/uv_index.htm) (Brannon):

- Season
- Altitude
- Time of day
- Ozone layer thickness (this can be quite variable on a local nd regional level)
- Cloud cover

to name a few, you would also require constant altitude alongside the constant atmospheric conditions mentioned in your question.